# How to make RepositoryItemCheckEdit to work like a radio?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a Devexpres `RepositoryItemCheckEdit` item. This repository is used in all cells from the `IncludedItems` column in a grid. Is there a easy way to force this Repository to work like a radio button ? I want to have only one item from the column checked at the time. If one item is checked and I check another the previous item should be unchecked automatically.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the  [How to implement a radio column](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E926.aspx) code central example to learn how this feature can be implemented.

Comment: I'm afraid i can't use your suggestion. The grid is part of a sealed class . I can only have access to the repository item and i hoped that maybe the Repository has a property that will solve my problem. Thanks for help.